# Making a craps game in python using a counter, but it won't count past 1

Tags: python, counter

I edited this down. What testCraps(number) does is that it calls a function called quietCraps() that returns a 1 for a win and a 0 for a loss. testCraps(number) is supposed to run quietCraps() a number of times equal to (number), adding 1 to winCoutner if a 1 is returned and adding 1 to lossCounter if a 0 is returned.

```
def testCraps(number):
    winCounter = 0
    lossCounter = 0
    for test in range(number): 
        testGame = quietCraps(value1 = 1)
        if str(test) == "1":
            winCounter = winCounter + 1
        elif str(test) == "0":
            lossCounter = lossCounter + 1
    print("The amount of wins is " + str(winCounter))
    print("The amount of losses is " + str(lossCounter))
```

Just to clarify, a win will return a 1 and a loss will return a 0. I konw that the counter in testCraps(number) is counting, but it will only go up to 1 for both counters. For example:

```
testCraps(5)
0
1
1 
1
1
The amount of wins is 1
The amount of losses is 1
```

I'm sure the answer is pretty simple, but I'm at a loss. Can anyone help me? If I did anything wrong with my post, I'm sorry. This is my first time asking a question here.

Comment: This is a lot of code to have other people debug for you. You should reduce this down to a [mcve] that shows the problem.

Comment: Can you fix your indentation?

Comment: your tests `if str(test) == "1"` and similar for "0" are testing your loop variable, and ignoring your actual testGame. It will be 0 exactly once and it will be 1 exactly once. The rest of the time it will be 2, then 3, then 4. I suspect you don't want to test the "test" variable.

Comment: When a question starts with "so" it often ends up telling a story with many unimportant details. From the first word your attitude is wrong. Reduce it down to the few important facts. The discipline will help you think more clearly about your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for test in range(number): 
    testGame = quietCraps(value1 = 1)
    if str(test) == "1":
        winCounter = winCounter + 1
    elif str(test) == "0":
        lossCounter = lossCounter + 1
```

Here, `winCounter` is incremented when `test == 1`. This occurs once, as the for loop just goes up from `0` to `number`, and therefore both counters will have a result of 1. Are you trying to check `testGame` instead? That has a value of `None` because `quietcraps()` returns nothing.

```
def quietCraps():
    crapsTotal = craps(2) 
    return crapsTotal
```

This way `quietCraps()` returns a value and can be checked. Also, no need for the `value1` argument, as it isn't used. Similarly, no need to write `craps(value1 = 2`, just write `craps(2)`

```
for test in range(number): 
    testGame = quietCraps(value1 = 1)
    if testGame == 1:
        winCounter = winCounter + 1
    elif testGame == 0:
        lossCounter = lossCounter + 1
```

No need to convert the result to string, just check if the numbers match.

P.S

```
if value1 == 1 == True:
```

Just change this to `if value1 == 1`. No need to check if that is true, because *that's what it's checking!*